# wso2 entitlements from Java program

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, wso2, entitlements

wso2 identity server is installed and running. I was able to create a policy in it and test a simple scenario. There seems to be a lot of connecting pieces in into this.

it's not clear how to access policy from a Java program and programmatically pass in role, resource and check if logged in user is authorized for performing a particular action or not. I also have requirement to add/remove roles and resources programmatically. Couldn't find much info. Any pointers/examples would be appreciated.

Comment: try this https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml-samples/pep/SamplePEP/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/entitlement/samples/pep/EntitlementServiceClient.java

Comment: Thanks @Dakshika. will try with that. doesn't program need to tell which policy (policy name) that we want to run against? (because I have multiple policies).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorials on writing client

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml-samples/pep/SamplePEP/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/entitlement/samples/pep/EntitlementServiceClient.java

http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/12/entitlement-service-xacml-pdp-as-web.html

http://insightforfuture.blogspot.com/2012/09/xacml-policy-definition-pointpdp-proxy.html